# How are Taguchi orthogonal arrays derived?

Tags: references, experiment-design, orthogonal

I am implementing statistical analysis in a C# program and am using the [Taguchi Method](https://controls.engin.umich.edu/wiki/index.php/Design_of_experiments_via_taguchi_methods%3a_orthogonal_arrays) to do it (the Taguchi arrays are about a 1/4th of the way down the page).

The article in the above link mentions that you can look up smaller Taguchi arrays and derive others, but I can't seem to find any resource that explains how to derive these Taguchi arrays. I can hard-code the smaller arrays in my program, but I want to be able to derive the others.

Is there a resource or link that explains, as simply as possible, how to derive Taguchi arrays? Maybe would someone here be able to explain how to derive them?

Comment: Have you take a look at Collombier's or Tinson's books ?

Comment: What books are those?

Comment: Sorry, these high-quality books are written in French, but perhaps there exist English versions, I don't know ; http://books.google.fr/books?id=6fuG9PDhEf0C&dq=collombier+plans+d%27exp%C3%A9riences&hl=fr&source=gbs_navlinks_s and http://books.google.fr/books?id=sTWohxxiMHMC&hl=fr&source=gbs_navlinks_s

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting web-site [A Library of Orthogonal Arrays](http://neilsloane.com/oadir/) by N. J. A. Sloane

Then [Orthogonal Arrays : Theory and Applications](https://www.bookdepository.com/Orthogonal-Arrays-S-Hedayat/9781461271581?ref=grid-view&qid=1669343325668&sr=1-1) by  A.S. Hedayat,  N.J.A. Sloane and  John Stufken.

A more elementary book is [Orthogonal Array : A Guide Book for Beginners - Demystifying Software Testing](https://www.bookdepository.com/Orthogonal-Array-Ravishankar-Ramamurthy/9788191033632?ref=grid-view&qid=1669343683143&sr=1-3)

Comment: Do any of those say how the tables are actually *derived* though?

Comment: The TOC for *Orthogonal Arrays: Theory and Applications* has a chapter about the construction of orthogonal arrays. I couldn't find the text for that chapter (some other chapters are partly on Google Books) but it suggests the tables are derived from error correcting codes.

Comment: The Hedayat reference certainly have the theory